# Building a "Microsoft Project"-like data hierarchy using EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I'm looking to build a "Microsoft Project"-like data hierarchy using Entity Framework 6. Essentially what I need is a data structure that can keep track of varying levels of detail for a task. So I'm looking to build a structure that would support something like the following where a Task can have subtasks and subtasks can have subtasks and so on but it doesn't always nor is it always the same depth.

```
Task
-Task
--Task
--Task
--Task
---Task
---Task
--Task
```

*A number of other posts on here have mentioned that tree hierarchies are very difficult with Entity Framework but I haven't been able to find any information to indicate whether it has improved since EF4 and is now less difficult.*

I have a Task Model like follows however when I try to generate the database it is not generated as expected:

```
public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Predecessors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Successors { get; set; }
}
```

I'm expecting a database where I have a Tasks table as well as Children, Predecessors, and Successors tables however what I end up with is just a Tasks table with attributes as follows:

```
ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
Name = c.String(),
Task_ID = c.Int(),
Parent_ID = c.Int(),
Task_ID1 = c.Int(),
Task_ID2 = c.Int(),
```

Additionally I want to be able to associate multiple different pieces of data with each of these Tasks. So let's say my task is "Build a Table" and I'm keeping track of how long it takes for PersonA to build it vs. PersonB. What is the best way to go about associating that data with that Task? Should I use a TaskData object something like follows:

```
public class TaskData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int CompletionTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

To even further complicate things I also need to make the same Task object reusable across multiple different Tasks. e.g. "Build Playground A" may have subtask "Build a Table" of size 1 whereas "Build Playground B" may have subtask "Build a Table" of size 2 but I only want the "Build a Table" Task to exist once in the DB and then to associate the data through a TaskData object.

Hints or help in determining how to address any of the above issues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your hierarchy table isn't too difficult a concept once you get to grips with it.  I generally work database-first not code-first so I cannot help you with the class definitions as well as other, but the theory is as follows....

Your Task should look have the following columns:

- Id (This is your primary key (for example))
- ParentId (This is a nullable column of same type as Id)
- Anything else you need

You should then have a relationship defined where the table references itself with Id on the Primary Key side and ParentId on the Foreign Key side.

What you should NOT have are separate tables.  All tasks will be included in a single table.

Your TaskData should then define its own Id, and anything else you require.  If you want a TaskData to be reusable across multiple Tasks, then create a many-to-many table with both TaskDataId and TaskId columns, create a composite key with them both and link Tasks and TaskData via that table.  Any data specific to each relationship between Tasks and TaskData can be defined within the Link table.

Where you do have to be careful with hierarchies is how the query can get slow when you request a large amount of data. Each time you loop down the hierarchy EF will generate a separate query.  I highly recommend for retrieving full hierarchies that you implement a Stored Procedure that uses a Common Table Expression (CTE) and map that Stored Procedure in EF.

**EDIT - To help with Task class** (forgive me if not entirely right, but it should point you in the right direction).

1 - Create your task

```
public class Task
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int TaskId { get; private set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int? ParentTaskId { get; private set; }

[ForeignKey("ParentTaskId")]
public Task ParentTask { get; set; }

public List<Task> SubTasks { get; set; }

public Task()
{
SubTasks = new List<Task>();
}
}
```

2 - Add a DbSet auto property to your DbContext subclass

3 - Override the OnModelCreated method in your DbContext class to configure the association.

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    // Other stuff

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
            .HasMany(t => t.SubTasks)
            .WithOptional(t => t.ParentTask);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree there should only be one Tasks table, I was just thinking the others would keep track of how the tasks relate to one another. The only thing I'm struggling with in what you explained is how to keep track of the id's and get EF to generate the navigational tables.

Comment: @bbodenmiller Forgive me, I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  When you say keep track of the ID's are you referring to the "Children", "Predecessors" and "Successors" properties mentioned in your provided class?

Comment: @bbodenmiller In the aim of helping you out tonight, I've assumed you meant what I said above.  See how you define the bi-directional association in Step 3.